# How to call componentWillUpdate() to update a child components state?

Tags: reactjs, components

My toolbar is already rendered and i want to now call componentWillUpdate() on this toolbar when i need to update it's state?

**HomeScreen**

```
constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            pagenum: 0,
            toptoolbartitle: "default",
            homeviewtitle: "default",
        };
    }

    updateHomeViewTitle(viewtitle){
    console.log(viewtitle);
    this.state.homeviewtitle = viewtitle;
    console.log("homeviewtitle is now"+this.state.homeviewtitle);
}

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <TopToolbarAndroid
           defaulttitle={"default"} titleupdate={this.state.homeviewtitle}/>
                    <RNCamera updateviewtitle={this.updateHomeViewTitle.bind(this)} />
                    <BottomBar />
            </View>

        </View>
```

**TopToolbarAndroid**

```
constructor(props){
        super();
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            pagenum: 0,
            title: this.props.defaulttitle
        };
    }

    componentWillUpdate(){
    console.log("component will update?");
    if (this.props.titleupdate != null)
    {console.log("updating toolbar title to: "+this.props.titleupdate);
        this.setState({title: this.props.titleupdate});}
}


  render() {    
    return (
        <ToolbarAndroid
              title= {this.state.title}
              style={styles.toolbar}
        />
    );
  }
```

**Result**
The componentWillUpdate is not updating the toolbars title, its not being called (re-rendered).

Comment: if i try using forceUpdate() after the callback updates the homeviewtitle, it causes an infinite loop. Im not sure which part of the spec https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html
Im misintepreting.

Comment: I also tried componentWillMount instead of componentWillUpdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not maintain state in `TopToolbarAndroid`. 
Just do this tweak in `TopToolbarAndroid` to update title-

`title={this.props.titleupdate ? this.props.titleupdate : this.props.defaulttitle}`

Get rid of `this.state` too.

I'm not sure what `this.props = props` does in the constructor. I'd just do `super(props)`.

Let me know, if this doesn't work. Please provide a link to runnable app as well, so that people can solve your problem effectively. Add a tag of `react-native` to your question to attract the right kind of people.

Host your example here - https://rnplay.org/